# how to merge two yml file with same parameter name and different children?

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, yaml

I added YML file to dependency injection folder in each bundle :

```
class GRFBlogExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('parameters.yml');
    }
}
```

and load parameters.yml per bundle
i have something like this in parameters.yml for each bundle , for example:

BlogBundle:

```
 parameters:
    adminmenu:
        BlogBundle:
            User:
              title: Users
              path: '/admin/User'
```

ShopBundle:

```
parameters:
    adminmenu:
        ShopBundle:
            category:
              title: Categories
              path: '/admin/category'
```

I want to merge these files like this when call getParameter('adminmenu'):

```
parameters:
      adminmenu:
          BlogBundle:
              category:
                title: Categories
                path: '/admin/category'
          ShopBundle:
              User:
                title: Users
                path: '/admin/User'
```

but just one keep in adminmenu and adminmenu element **override** by newer file.
**Help me please.thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 1 way to do it.
get this parameter in Extention for Bundle before load new parameters.

Something like that:

```
class GRFBlogExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

       $adminMenuKey     = 'adminmenu';
       $coreAdminMenu    = $container->getParameter($uiMapKey);
       $loader           = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
       $loader->load('services.yml');
       $branchAdminMenu  = $container->getParameter($adminMenuKey);
       $groupedAdminMenu = $coreAdminMenu + $branchAdminMenu;
       $container->setParameter($adminMenuKey, $groupedAdminMenu);
    }
}
```